# How to point scons to a different compiler installed in my home directory?

Tags: python, scons

I have tried editing SConstruct to point to a different gcc compiler but it always seems to use the one defined in /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/g++.

```
env = DefaultEnvironment()
env['CC'] = '/home/aaron/devel/bin/gcc'
env['CXX'] = '/home/aaron/devel/bin/g++'
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a way to specify a different compiler on the command line using something like:

```
scons cxx=/home/aaron/devel/bin/g++
```

I've gone crazy trying to make this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a suggestion in "Why doesn't SCons find my compiler/linker/etc.?" in the [SCons wiki](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.)?  For your case, that would be

```
path = ['/path/to/other/compiler/bin', '/bin', '/usr/bin',]
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path})
```

i.e., make your own environment with exactly the content you want, such as the `$PATH` (other bits of useful advice about environments are close by in the same wiki page).

To add your own options to scons' command line, per [the docs](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.0.0/HTML/scons-user/c1965.html#sect-command-line-options), you should be able to use `AddOption`, see section 12.1.5 (but, I have not tried this one myself).

Comment: AddOption is the right way to do this. You can also use ARGUMENTS.get('cxx') but then that is not sticky.

Answer (score 0):

A "dirty trick" is "just" to make a symbolic link to the new interpretor in the folder where you issue the scons command