# How to use scons for cross build

Tags: python, c, linux, scons

I am trying to create the simplest imaginable SConstruct file for cross compiling a program.
I tried different settings, the latest SConstruct file is here:

```
env_options = {
    "CC"    : "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc",
    "CXX"   : "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++",
    "LD"    : "arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld",
    "AR"    : "arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar",
    "STRIP" : "arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip"
}
env = Environment(**env_options)
path = ['/path/to/toolchain/bin/']
env.Append( ENV = {'PATH' : path})

p = Program( "prog", [ "prog.c", "mylib.c" ], CFLAGS=[ '-Iinclude', '-Werror', '-Wall', '-Wextra' ] )
```

The output of `env.Dump()` shows e.g.:

```
{ 'AR': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar',
  'CC': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc',
  'CXX': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++',
  'ENV': { 'PATH': [ '/path/to/toolchain/bin/']},
  'LD': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld',
  'TOOLS': [ 'default',
         'gnulink',
         'gcc',
         'g++',
         'gas',
         'ar',
         'filesystem',
         'm4',
         'zip']
}
```

I don't see any surprises in the `env.Dump()` output (especially no standard system paths), and thought that in case scons can not find the tools listed in `env_options` I would at least get an error message.
Instead, scons uses the default tools and builds the program for my host system.
I've considered the answers posted [here(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898584/how-can-i-use-a-cross-compiler-with-scons) and [here(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304095/how-to-point-scons-to-a-different-compiler-installed-in-my-home-directory) - with no success so far.

- What do I miss?
- How is it possible that scons still finds and uses the default tools (I explicitly stated to use a binary `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3` and there are no system paths like `/bin/` or `/usr/bin` set in ENV )?
- How can I force scons to explicitly only use the paths/tools that I'm passing (build an environment from scratch)?

Comment: Same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31232955/172599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = Program( "prog", [ "prog.c", "mylib.c" ], CFLAGS=[ '-Iinclude', '-Werror', '-Wall', '-Wextra' ] )
```

Should be

```
p = env.Program( "prog", [ "prog.c", "mylib.c" ], CFLAGS=[ '-Iinclude', '-Werror', '-Wall', '-Wextra' ] )
```

Using Program instead of env.Program uses the default environment which doesn't have CC,etc set to any non-default values.